# I am working on an assignment. and I am not able to arrange the data in order

Tags: r, database, dataframe, sorting, ranking

```r
if (outcome == "Pneumonia"){
    
    temp[order(temp$Lower.Mortality.Estimate...Hospital.30.Day.Death..Mortality..Rates.from.Pneumonia,decreasing = TRUE),]
    d<-data.frame(temp$Hospital.Name,temp$Lower.Mortality.Estimate...Hospital.30.Day.Death..Mortality..Rates.from.Pneumonia)
    print(d)
```

I tried to use order function. I have also tried to use arrange function from dplyr but I am getting the output as following, which is not arranged. I don't know what mistake i am doing here. If anyone can help, it will be great

```r
[1] "10.0" "10.1" "10.1" "10.3" "10.4" "10.5" "10.5" "10.6" "11.0" "11.5" "5.9"  "6.4"  "7.1"  "7.1"  "7.3"  "7.5"  "7.6"  "7.6"  "7.7" 
[20] "7.7"  "7.8"  "7.8"  "7.8"  "7.8"  "7.9"  "8.2"  "8.2"  "8.2"  "8.3"  "8.3"  "8.4"  "8.5"  "8.6"  "8.6"  "8.7"  "8.8"  "8.8"  "8.9" 
[39] "9.0"  "9.0"  "9.4"  "9.4"  "9.5"  "9.7"  "9.9"
```

Comment: The values are character strings and not numbers.  You will need to convert first. See the `as.numeric()` function.

Comment: Note that there is an ordering to your data.  It is ordered by the leading digits of the character string.  You will have first have to convert the characters to numeric as @Dave2e said, and then reorder.